# Disabling a href tag if the php variable link is null

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Below variable are stored in mysql table but sometimes some links are empty.How to check if each one is NULL and then disable if content is NULL (0) just to not be selected, because if they empty they holds main link of article.

```
<?php
echo "<span><strong>DOWNLOADs<strong></span><br/><br>
    <a href=".$link1.">link</a><br/>
    <a href=".$link2.">link1</a><br/>
    <a href=".$link3.">link2</a><br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will **`disable`** it, instead of masking

By using inline ternary operator over 
[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function who : Determine whether a variable is empty

```
$var = (condition) 
? 'value_0'  // if true
: 'value_1'  // if false
```

Look for the documentation : [Ternary comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
<?php

$link2 = "http://someurl..";

echo "<span><strong>DOWNLOADs<strong></span><br/><br>
    <a ".(!empty($link1) ? "href='$link1'":"").">link</a><br/>
    <a ".(!empty($link2) ? "href='$link2'":"").">link1</a><br/>
    <a ".(!empty($link3) ? "href='$link3'":"").">link2</a><br/>";
?>
```

Will ouput whole tags link preserved to make only != null active

```
<span><strong>DOWNLOADs<strong></span><br/><br>
    <a>link</a><br/>
    <a href='http://someurl..'>link1</a><br/>
    <a>link2</a><br/>
```

Comment: Yes it works like a charm.Thanks!
Can you explain how it works code what makes " : " ?

Comment: updated answer with more explanation an documentation

Answer (score 0):

Check if a link is empty before outputing it :

```
<?php
echo "<span><strong>DOWNLOADs<strong></span><br/><br>";

if (!empty($link1)) {
    echo "<a href=\"".$link1."\">link</a><br/>";
}

... and so on
```

Comment: Thanks it works!
But can I check in this way if ($link1 && $link2 && $link3){}

Comment: If you do that the links will all need to be filled to be displayed. But yes yo can do if (!empty($link1) && !empty($link2) ...